# Adobe Air Can't Connect to Server on iOS10

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, ios10, animate-cc

I have an application on Appstore like 2 years.
I developed with Adobe AIR.

On iOS10 my app not working. Can't connect to http links.

I debug and get error from connections:
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://api.website.net/check.php

I used HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS for understand any solution, it gives 0

Any methods to solve?

**MY CODE:**

```
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://api.website.net/check.php");            
urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;          
var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();          
urlVars.user_id = Main.instance.userID;     
urlReq.data = urlVars; 


var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (urlReq);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCreditComplete);


loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);


loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.load(urlReq);
```

Comment: Could be anything from _using non `https` link_ to possibly it's _a non 64-bit app_. Apple's expectations for apps have changed. I can't answer you but just investigate while waiting for an Answer. For example test that URLRequest for loading some text file from a `http` url vs loading from `https` url. If both work on iOS testings, that'll be one issue eliminated etc..

Comment: I found errors about server requirements.
Found a https link to try and that work. But my http link not working.
Some forums says iPv6 must supported on your server.
Do you know which requirements need to work with iOS10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like it's related to the iOS App Transport security settings.

To enable `http` requests you will need to either define the domains as exceptions in your application descriptor:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>api.website.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

or add a global ignore security setting:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

---

These settings should be added to the `InfoAdditions` node in your iPhone settings of your application descriptor:

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>

        <!-- Add the above settings here -->

    ]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
    <Entitlements>
        <![CDATA[
        ]]>
    </Entitlements>
</iPhone>
```